# Pyppeteer (python) - clink a tag and after scraping the page

Tags: python, web-scraping, pyppeteer

I am new to Pyppeteer (Python) and I am trying to know how to (in order):

1. log into the page
2. clink a tag
3. take the data from the tag which I have clinked

The website is 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/login'

I think I managed to solve the first part which is logging in. However, I have difficulties in the second and third.

Appreciate if someone can guide me via python examples on this. For example, clinking the Tags = 'inspirational' under the third quotes (by Einstein) and taking all the quotes from the 'inspirational' page.

```
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
from pyppeteer import launch

username = 'AAA'
password = 'BBB'
 
async def main():
 #   browser = await launch(headless=False, args=['--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'])
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36')
    await page.goto('https://quotes.toscrape.com/login',)
    
    await page.waitForSelector( '[id="username"]')
    await page.focus('[id="username"]')
    await page.keyboard.type(username)
    
    await page.waitForSelector( '[id="password"]')
    await page.focus('[id="password"]')
    await page.keyboard.type(password)
    
    await asyncio.wait([
    page.click('[type="submit"]'),
    page.waitForNavigation()])
    
    
    
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: You're selecting items with css selectors, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to main()

```
 page.click('span.tag-item:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)')
 quotelist = page.JJ(".quote") #alias to querySelectorAll()
 quotetext = quotelist.JJeval('.text', '(nodes => nodes.map(n => n.innerText))')
 return quotetext
```

I wrote this based on their docs here https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#browser-class

Of course JS is a much better language to work with webpages, so for more comlicated stuff I'd use JS based web **scrapers**

Comment: I got an error on the 'feedhandle' (name 'feedHandle' is not defined).. How do I resolve that ?

Comment: @Omerge I am sorry, I forgot to rename the variable name. Try it now.

Comment: Hey thanks alot. Unfortunately, I still face an error... the error is 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'JJeval'... I believe there is an error start at 'page.JJ' as well... Is that a module I need to install for 'JJ' ?

Comment: @Omerge the page.JJ is a function from pyppeteer module.

Comment: @Omerge How about now? If you want I can give you the JS code I started with.

Comment: Thanks. But no luck. I still face the same error. I have looked at the api document and I think your code make sense. fyi an 'await' is needed for the clink => await page.clink...
  

<ipython-input-1-79c6691b7ec1> in main()
     31 
     32     quotelist = page.JJ(".quote") #alias to querySelectorAll()
---> 33     quotetext = quotelist.JJeval('.text', '(nodes => nodes.map(n => n.innerText))')
     34 
     35     return quotetext

AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'JJeval'

Comment: The code once you're on the page:                                                                                       `var els = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/tag/inspirational/']");
els[0].click();
let testss = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
for(x of tests){
  console.log(x.innerText)
}`

Comment: You might use the JS code with  addScriptTag in pyppeteer

Comment: @Omerge So what the answer is? You can help others by updating your post.

Comment: I have used this instead:
quotes = []
await page.waitForSelector('.quote')
    quoteElements = await page.querySelectorAll('.quote')
    
    for quoteElement in quoteElements:
        textElement = await quoteElement.querySelector('.text')
        text = await page.evaluate('el => el.textContent', textElement)
        
        quotes.append(text)
    
    return quotes

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question on your CSS on page.click('span.tag-item:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)').... I try to play around with the child(n) but I couldn't figure out the pattern where it locate. How does the logic work ? (for example getting tag 'Classic' under the fourth quote by Jane.... 

I hope I am not taking too much of your time...

Comment: The easiest way is through browser devtools. Select the element you need in Inspector and right click, select css selector